# Is this a bug in java jdk?

Tags: java, windows, file

When I got a java.lang.File class with the code `File file = new File("e:/");`, of course I got a File class represented the e:\ directory.

But if I got a File class with code `File file = new File("e:");` and I just in the drive E:, then I got a File class represented current directory.

Assume I'm in directory E:\dir\, And this directory have a file named Test.java.
It's content is:

```
import java.io.File;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("e:"); 
        File[] files = file.listFiles(); 
        for(File f: files){ 
            System.out.println(f + " " + f.exists()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Open the cmd tool and navigate to the directory e:\dir, execute the following command in it:

```
E:\dir> javac Test.java
E:\dir> java Test
```

I got:

```
e:\Test.class false
e:\Test.java false
```

Is this a java jdk bug?

---

Additional information from @JimGarrison:

I ran this code

```
public class Foo3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception
    {
        File f = new File("D:");
        System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
        for (File x : f.listFiles())
            System.out.println(x + " " + x.getCanonicalPath() + " " + x.getAbsolutePath() + " " + x.exists() + " " + x.getAbsoluteFile().exists());
    }
}
```

in Eclipse (which lives on my D: drive) and got the following output:

```
D:\dev\src\pdxep
D:\.classpath D:\dev\src\pdxep\.classpath D:\dev\src\pdxep\.classpath false true
D:\.project D:\dev\src\pdxep\.project D:\dev\src\pdxep\.project false true
D:\.settings D:\dev\src\pdxep\.settings D:\dev\src\pdxep\.settings false true
D:\gallery D:\dev\src\pdxep\gallery D:\dev\src\pdxep\gallery false true
D:\pom.xml D:\dev\src\pdxep\pom.xml D:\dev\src\pdxep\pom.xml false true
D:\src D:\dev\src\pdxep\src D:\dev\src\pdxep\src false true
D:\target D:\dev\src\pdxep\target D:\dev\src\pdxep\target false true
```

Which confirms there's something funny going on.

Java [Bug 8130462](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8130462) seems to be related as it has to do with relative vs absolute paths specifically in Windows.

Comment: Very curious.  I can reproduce the problem as well.

Comment: I ran the program as written above (though I modified the class name to TestFile), and received expected output (files and directories listed, etc.) for the e: drive (Windows 10). Running Java 1.8.0_72. @JimGarrison it is interesting you reproduced the issue. Ran it both from within Eclipse and at command line. Only difference is that I had a package name so it was java -cp ./bin package.TestFile

Comment: If you run in a debugger and stop at the `println` you can see that there's a difference between the path and the canonical path.  The output you see (missing the current directory) seems to be what is used to look for the file, but printing the canonical path includes the current directory.  Sure looks like a bug (likely in the implementation of the Windows filesystem provider).  Creating a File from a an explicit full path string does not have this problem.

Comment: @KevinO Perhaps you're running from the root and not a folder off the root? I can reproduce as well - very odd. I agree it's an issue in the FileSystem as the first line in the File c'tor is *this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);* where fs is *FileSystem*

Comment: OK, I actually had one slight difference. I was running from my f: drive, not the e: drive (but listing the e: drive). Changing the code from "e:" to "f:" resulted in the incorrect output, per the question and the results observed by @JimGarrison. So, it works fine for me if I use just the drive letter and am on a drive different from the one where I attempt to list the files.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.  Since there's at least one long-standing bug in `File` having to do with absolute vs relative paths, I suspect this is another (or a consequence of the existing bug, linked in my update to the question).

Comment: I have submitted a bug report on Oracle's Java site.  We'll see what happens, and I will update here when I hear back.  I'd post a bug number and link but submitting a bug gives no feedback. I guess they triage before the publish on the Java bug list.

Comment: It's more likely to be a peculiarly of the Windws API.

Comment: This is how drive letters work in the command prompt, too, so maybe it's not a bug, but a feature.

Answer (score 1):

The first part about getting a `File` representing the current working directory with code `File file = new File("e:");` is not a bug. It is a Windows "drive relative path". That is, a path relative to the current working directory in the specified drive. (Yes, Windows have a different working director per drive)

The issue is that Java wrongly adds a `\` after the drive-letter in the path which makes the path look like an absolute path, and wrongly returns `false` on `file.exists()` probably because of that.

However, Java correctly resolves the canonical-path and absolute-path and correctly returns true on `x.getAbsoluteFile().exists()`. Java also correctly returns the contents of the `CWD` in `file.listFiles()` as you noticed in your example code.

I found an old bug in the database which [JDK-5066567](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5066567) about this or at least very similar to this. It was created in 2004 and set to "In progress" 2013 and the current Assignee is "Inactive" so I don't think we will see any fix for this soon, if ever.

So to answer you question, I would say yes, it is a bug.

However, it seems like it is better handled in `java.nio.file.Path`. So if it is possible to use the `java.nio.file.*` package instead in your use case, it might be a acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug.

- `E:/` means that you specify both a drive *and* a directory
- `E:` means you only specify a drive, the directory is left to the default value.

Note: Now what people think of as *current* directory is actually *default* directory. i.e. what is applied by default when none is specified. 
It's just the same if you don't specify the drive at all, the default (current default) will apply.

This is the way it works on most File Systems.

Comment: Interesting about the default directory, did not know this. Could you provide a link to read more about this. However, file.exists() should still return true regardless of this, and that is the bug, so I am sorry but in that respect I think you are wrong. Or do you have an explanation of this behavior?

Comment: 'Current working directory' has been the term in use for decades, and that's why for example the `pwd` command isn't spelt `pdd`. Not much point in trying to change the name now.

Comment: @EJP, then may be you can explain why in venerable VMS's command language (called DCL), the cd command is actually `set default`. And BTW, do I need to remind you that the chief architect of Windows was Dave Cuttler, also the architect of VMS?

Comment: @gustf, file.exists() adds the default directory if there is none specified, or uses the one specified, if any. But I agree with all the observations you have made and that the behaviour is at the very least inconsistent.

Comment: @gustf, example on OpenVMS, `cd e:\ ` would be invoked as `set default e:\ ` or actually `set default $E:[000000]`. [Syntax](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/9996/9996pro_182.html)